# Symfony 4 implement REST API

Tags: php, rest, api, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm implementing a simple REST API in my Symfony 4 project. When I test the getArticle() function with Postman this is the error:

> The controller must return a response (Object(FOS\RestBundle\View\View) given).

With a var_dump($articles) content is displayed as expected so I guess the problem could be the FOSRestBundle but I don't know other ways to do this job.

```
class ArticleController extends FOSRestController
{

/**
 * Retrieves an Article resource
 * @Rest\Get("/articles/{id}")
 */
public function getArticle(int $articleId): View
 {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $article = $em->getRepository(Article::class)->findBy(array('id' => $articleId));

    // In case our GET was a success we need to return a 200 HTTP OK response with the request object
    return View::create($article, Response::HTTP_OK);
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't use the bundle myself but a cursory check of the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/2-the-view-layer.html) seems to show using a "$view = $this->view($products, 200)" to create a view instead of View::create as well as "return $this->handleView($view);" Are you following some other article or tutorial?

Comment: And while a bit off topic, I think the [api-platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/core) might be a more widely used approach.

Comment: I've tried out with both methods and none of them work. Api platform is good but I need a custom controller.

Comment: You need to use `return $this->handleView($view);` rather than return the `View` object.

Comment: return $this->handleView($view) gives the error: "You have requested a non-existent service "fos_rest.view_handler".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution by myself returning a HttpFoundation\Response, it might be helpful to someone.

```
/**
 * Lists all Articles.
 * @FOSRest\Get("/articles")
 */
public function getArticles(Request $request): Response
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $articles = $em->getRepository(Article::class)->findAll();

    return new Response($this->json($articles), Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Comment: Glad you got something working.  Might want to look at JsonResponse as well.  But just so you know, this solution is just the "out of the box" Symfony solution.  Nothing to do with the api bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Define a view response listener in your config/packages/fos_rest.yaml. For details why and what it does read the FOSRest documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/view_response_listener.html).

```
fos_rest:
  view:
    view_response_listener:  true
```

Also add this to your fos_rest.yaml to select your output format -> here json

```
fos_rest:
  [...] 
  format_listener:
    rules:
      - { path: ^/, prefer_extension: true, fallback_format: json, priorities: [ json ] }
```

Comment: I've read the documentation but the problem is that config/packages/fos_rest.yaml doesn't exist and if I try to create it, project dumps.

Comment: When installing fos rest bundle, it should have asked to install a third party recipe for creating a basic configuration. Maybe try removing and reinstalling fos rest bundle and install this recipe. fos_rest.yaml should be available then.

Comment: I've already tried and still doesn't work, the FOSRestBundle has probably been deprecated.

Comment: I'd say it looks like your project is broken. The recipe is supposed to create this file. Try to reinstall the whole project. If it still does'nt work post your composer.json.